# How to relate two averages to find a probability?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I would like to "relate" two arithmetic averages and then use them in Poisson. I currently already use a method, but i'm sure we can do better and that there is a better way. I currently sum the two averages, then divide by two, then use the result in Poisson

In the championship matches played so far, `Team_A` and `Team_B` have never clashed against each other, but so far the average number of `goals scored` by Team_A is `1.40`; Instead the average number of `goals conceded` by Team_B is `1.80`. I would like to calculate how many probabilità there are that Team_A scores 2 goals against Team_B in the next match when the two teams will clash against each other. The two averages are independent, because there is no correlation between the two datasets.

An important observation is that the goals scored by Team_A against Team_B will be the same as those that Team_B will concede from Team_A.

Is there any better way that can **replace** addition and division by 2? (my Union) and find a value to use in Poisson?

Thank you

Comment: Note that any computation of this kind will not "calculate" but at best estimate a probability. Also, it may be OK to assume the averages for the two teams against different opponents to be independent, but when they play against each other, how to combine the two bits of information realistically may depend on further knowledge. For example Team A may have played against teams of the same strength as Team B before, but Team B may have played against better teams. Averaging 1.4 and 1.8 looks OK if you don't know anything better, but that doesn't mean it's realistic.

Comment: @ChristianHennig The example you gave is true, you're right, but it gets too complicated in this case, because "weighted" values should be applied in relation to the opponent. Let's ignore this which is another matter. I was looking for something better than the simple average between 1.4 and 1.8. Is there some theorem or distribution I could use to "relate" the two averages? Vedo che stai a Bologna. Bellissima Bologna :D

Comment: Grazie! I don't know of anything better if you don't have more prior information to involve.

Comment: @ChristianHennig What additional preliminary information would you need to know?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, and I don't have the time to go into detail here. There are many possible kinds of information that could help somehow.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Okay. Just tell me one thing, a curiosity: in the absence of information, is the way I used TEAM_A__Goals_Scored + TEAM_B__Goals_Granted) / 2 correct? (I'm speaking from a logical point of view). I am aware that it is not very realistic, but is it logically correct to add the two averages and then divide by 2?

Comment: As I said before, I wouldn't call it "correct", but I'd say I can't think of anything better, in which sense at least it's not wrong.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Okay. However, in case you would like to help me, I have updated the question and inserted some new data. Some Probability Theory could be applied. If you don't want to help me, I understand, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I find this question unanswerable because literally any (positive) number could be justified.  The outcome of any game depends on an interaction between *both* teams and you have no information about this particular pair of teams.  The best advice, then, is the kind you are getting from @Christian concerning the limitations of your information and the fact that anything you conclude will not be provably wrong but could be useless or misleading.  One could make progress by adopting assumptions about interactions, but that would be a guessing game on our part, which doesn't work in this format.

Comment: @whuber Christian said several things. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: All of them.... .

Answer (score 2):

Another issue you might want to think about is that a team might be good at offence, and poor at defence. The defensive strength of a team can be estimated by the number of goals it concedes, and the offensive strength by the number of goals it scores.

There is another complication. A human predictor would be capable of reasoning: Manchester City have scored many goals this season, but so far they have played only weak opponents. Manchester United have scored fewer goals, but they have played strong opponents.

I suggest that the quality of each team should be represented by two number, and the number of goals predicted in a match should be estimated as a Poisson distribution of offensive strength divided by defensive strength. Then use a Bayesian software package to find maximum likelihood estimates of strength, given the data.

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but a little vague. You talk about offensive strength and defensive strength, ok, perfect :) Then you talk about Poisson. I already use Poisson, but to calculate a given goal in relation to the simple average. QUESTION: It seems like you want to make a different use of Poisson, because you talk about dividing the offensive strength by the defensive strength, but I don't understand. Can you explain better please? (maybe with an example)

Comment: (continuation of above comment) In my case TEAM_A__Total_Goals_Scored / TEAM_B__Total_Goals_Granted? So 7 / 9 = 0.77, so use 0.77 in Poisson? (I don't think that's what you meant though)

Comment: Yes, I assume: predicted goals scored by team A is offensive strength of A / defensive strength of B, and actual goals scored is a Poisson distribution with the mean as that prediction.

Comment: @chrismorris
 I tried using 0.77 in Poisson. The probability of scoring 0 goals is 46.30%, that of scoring 1 goal is 35.65%, that of scoring 2 goals is 13.72%. Considering my basic data (Team A scored 7 goals and Team B allowed 9 goals), isn't the Poisson probability of scoring 1 goal with 35.65% too low? I have 2 questions please: 1. I was thinking: isn't 0.77 too small a number to use in Poisson and therefore it falsifies the result a bit? 2. You talked about using Bayesian software package to find the best force estimates, can you explain this further? Can you give an example? Thank you

Comment: @chrismorris  Why did you delete all the comments (mine and yours) in which you talked about Bayes packages and suggested Bayes Optimization? Wasn't it the right method? Your response is very vague and your behavior was not the most respectful or courteous

Comment: Chris did not delete those comments: a diamond moderator did *in response to your flag!*  If that puzzles you, then please take some time to read over our [help] to learn how this site works.